# Running shell script from external drive via live user

Tags: permissions

I've tried at least 15 different solutions at this point, and none have worked. I'm using a Mint 18.1 live boot drive, and trying to run a shell script on a separate drive. It simply says "permission denied" so I tried `sudo chmod 777 /path/to/file.sh` but to no avail. It *looks* like it completes, but a quick run of `stat /path/to/file.sh` says otherwise. I tried making a file */etc/udev/rules.d/90-usb-disks.rules* with the data:

```
# UDEV Rules to change the permission of USB disks
#

KERNEL=="sd*[0-9]", ATTR{removable}=="1", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", MODE="0022"
```

which also didn't do anything. I tried remounting the drive with `rwx` permissions, but NOPE! Is there ***anything*** that will let this work?!

Side note: this script may be starting other scripts in the same folder, I don't know, so that's something to consider. Also, sorry for being a Linux noob - we all start somewhere.

Comment: As a side note, it's better to use `chmod +x file` if you want it to be executable.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex tried that. Same outcome as `chmod 777`

Comment: Can we see what your script does? Sounds like executing it, produces that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your external drive's filesystem doesn't support Linux/UNIX style permissions (FAT32, etc.), unfortunately chmod and friends will not return an error in this situation, they will simply be unable to set/change permissions.

Also, the `MODE` option in your udev rule affects the permissions of the device node (in /dev) for the filesystem itself: e.g. `/dev/sdc1`, not for the filesystem's contents..

That being said, there are a couple of possibilities - first, and easiest, would simply be to pass the script as an argument to the appropriate shell, e.g. `bash /path/to/file.sh`

This will have issues, however, if `file.sh` happens to call, for example, `otherfile.sh` inside of it.. you could, of course, modify the script to call bash as above, else you will need to ensure the filesystem is actually mounted with executable bit set for files.

In my experience, "automatic" mounts usually err on the side of caution and do not enable execute by default, but if you mount the filesystem manually from the command line as root it defaults to having all files executable... so, you could unmount the drive (remove safely, etc) from the GUI, then open a terminal and enter something like

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```

replacing /dev/sdc1 with your filesystem location (if in doubt, run `dmesg` and it should give you a clue the device name  you'll need here.

If for some reason that still mounts without the execute bit set for files the options are filesystem specific for umask, fmask, dmask, mode, etc.  `man mount` and check *options for your_filesystem_type*

Comment: This worked perfectly! I did need to use `sudo fsck -t fat /dev/sdc1` and remove a dirty bit, but other than that, this was golden. Thank you!